# Getting certificate name from a smart card

Tags: java, certificate, itext, digital-certificate

I am using the following code to list the certificates on my smart card:

```
Enumeration enumeration = ks.aliases();

        while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String aliass = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("alias name: " + aliass);
       }
```

Lets say that on the smart card I have a cert named John Smith , and the CA is StartCom. The above listing gives me a result like : John Smith's StartCom Ltd. ID, and I am trying to get just John Smith.

Can anybody help??

Comment: does anybody have an idea?

Comment: If the enumeration tells you that "John Smith's StartCom Ltd. ID" is the alias there, then your expectation that there instead is an alias "John Smith" is wrong.

Comment: when I insert the card, I see token with just John Smith(I used john smith and startcom as an example for not to put valid certificate and CA on here). and when I sign the pdf and it is certified in the top of the document i get the blue ribbon saying John Smith, then email adress then CA and so on... so it is issued for John Smith(not John Smith's StartCom Ltd), but in my signature that uses the mentioned function I get John Smith's StartCom Ltd.... Hope I explained it. I may be still be wrong in my expectations? @mkl

Comment: The alias is not necessarily one of the labels you describe. I assume those labels are derived from subject entry of the certificate, not from the alias. You might want to retrieve the certificate for the alias and analyze its subject.

Comment: Yes you are right, I listed all the cert fields and saw that what I want is Subject CN field... but don't know how to retrieve it @mkl

Comment: I would propose you either create a new question or edit this question to reflect that you want to read certain certificate fields. I assume, though, that the Sun/Oracle security related tutorial paths contains the answer.

Comment: thanks, i will create another question and also look at the Oracle docs @mkl